# pass context of activity in AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} nested in fragment - The method is undefined

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a problem with pass the context of activity in this method

```
        private void registerClicksOnParents(ListView listView, final Dialog d, final   
        ImageButton btn, final ChildAndActivityDataClass currentChild) {
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                d.dismiss();
                btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.odebrany);
                btn.setEnabled(false);          
                currentChild.setOdbiorDzieckaIdOfState(App_class.odebrane);
                SingleInfoToServer singleInfoToServer = SingleInfoToServer(currentChild.getIdOfChild(), 
                                                                           currentChild.getOdbiorDzieckaIdOfActivity(), 
                                                                           currentChild.getOdbiorDzieckaIdOfState(),
                                                                           context);
            }               
        });


    }
```

When I invoke this method in `onItemClick` I can't use `getActivity`, I try with, `MainScreen.this` but nothing works. I try to get context in Fragment onCreate method this way:

```
public class Aktywnosci_Fragment extends Fragment {

Context context ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getActivity();

}
```

but it stills shows the same `The method SingleInfoToServer(int, int, int, Context) is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}`

This method constructor looks like this

```
public SingleInfoToServer( int idOfChild,  int idOfActivity, int idOfState, Context context) 
{
    this.context = context;     
    this.idOfChild = idOfChild;
    this.idOfActivity = idOfActivity;
    this.idOfState = idOfState;
}
```

so everything should works

EDIT as you said in comments I tried with this

private void registerClicksOnParents(ListView listView, final Dialog d, final ImageButton btn, final ChildAndActivityDataClass currentChild, final Activity activity) {
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                d.dismiss();
                btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.odebrany);
                btn.setEnabled(false);          
                currentChild.setOdbiorDzieckaIdOfState(App_class.odebrane);
                SingleInfoToServer singleInfoToServer = SingleInfoToServer(currentChild.getIdOfChild(), 
                                                                           currentChild.getOdbiorDzieckaIdOfActivity(), 
                                                                           currentChild.getOdbiorDzieckaIdOfState(),
                                                                           view.getContext());

            }       

    }       );  
        }
```

and nothing changes

Comment: use `view.getContext()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I invoke this method in onItemClick I can't use getActivity, I
>   try with, MainScreen.this but nothing works

Instead of storing Context reference,you can get it using `view.getContext()` in `onItemClick`.

To create `SingleInfoToServer` object also use `new` keyword as:

```
SingleInfoToServer singleInfoToServer = new SingleInfoToServer(
                                                 currentChild.getIdOfChild(),
                                  currentChild.getOdbiorDzieckaIdOfActivity(), 
                  currentChild.getOdbiorDzieckaIdOfState(), view.getContext());
```

Comment: This nothing changes for me:  SingleInfoToServer singleInfoToServer = SingleInfoToServer(currentChild.getIdOfChild(), 
                      currentChild.getOdbiorDzieckaIdOfActivity(), 
                      currentChild.getOdbiorDzieckaIdOfState(),
                      view.getContext()); and this same error still

Comment: @MyWay : Do it as `SingleInfoToServer singleInfoToServer = new SingleInfoToServer(currentChild.getIdOfChild(), currentChild.getOdbiorDzieckaIdOfActivity(), currentChild.getOdbiorDzieckaIdOfState(), view.getContext());`

Comment: OO omg I'm just blind idiot, there was lack of new in declaration, programming when u are sick rocks :D, thx for help

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch getActivity() response with an Activity object. Then from the activity you can get that context.